# WCF service only receiving 65536 String.Length size only, not more than that

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, servicecontract, operationcontract

I have created a WCF service which receives String (Text/Json) as a request, but the problem is it is only able to receive String length of 65536 (String.Length). I have tried below (binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647") by googling but there is no change it is only able to receive 65536 of String.Length size only not more that. I am newbee to the dotNet and WCF word, can someone help me to send large data to this service (I wanted to send around 10MB of data to my WCF service).

```
   My Server Config:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="[my-service-name]">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8005/MyService"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="[my-service-contract-name]"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <startup> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
      </startup>
    </configuration>


    My Service:

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "MyService")]
        void MyService(String input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request data = " + input.Length);
        }



Client Config:    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="name-here" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior-here">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

binding attribute for your service is set to webHttpBinding and you are adding attributes like maxReceivedMessageSize under basicHttpBinding. I believe it is just defaulting to the webHttpbinding attributes. I would recommend, create a binding under your httpBinding and make all the desired changes maxReceivedMessageSize under your new binding and tie it your service with the name of the binding as below :

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testMessageBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="30000000" openTimeout="00:00:02" receiveTimeout="00:00:02" sendTimeout="00:00:02" closeTimeout="00:00:02">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

---

Hope this helps and also read the below link to get more knowledge on custom binding, system-provided etc if you have not looked at the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/system-provided-bindings

Answer (score 0):

```
In your config, please add
"<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>"

Service Config:
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

Client Config:
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I still see same issue "Excption : The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."